# What does this part mean in Netbeans (PHP)?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

So I understand it has to do something with memory, but what exactly does it indicate? Because it starts "filling up" even when my website is not running. Does it show a memory leak or something about my code (as I said it fills up without running the website so probably not)? Or is it just about the IDE itself and has nothing to do with my code? Thanks in advance!

This is the picture of the part I'm speaking about -
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows the memory usage of the IDE itself. The reason it builds up is that the garbage collector is only run at intervals, when it removes unused objects from memory (a simplification!). The bar can be clicked to force garbage collection.

It can be toggled from "View/Toolbars/Performance".

Comment: Thanks for you answer.